# Java synchronized passing object to alien method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, synchronized

I have an object passed into a function which passes a delayed runnable to a handler.

I can lock the object when it gets passed in and when it gets changed using the lock object but then the object needs to get passed out to an 'alien' method upload.

How can I ensure this alien method upload does not break the thread safety of my object?

It has objects passed in from elsewhere not just this delay thread so the object lock is not valid and it encompasses quite a lot of functionality so I'm concerned about locking the entire call with the lock object.

```
private ContentValues mEvent;
protected final Object mEventLock = new Object();

public void delayFunction(final Values e) {

    // Sanity check
    if (e == null) {
        return;
    }

    synchronized (mEventLock) {
        mEvent = e;
    }

    this.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (prefs != null) {
                final String refs = prefs.getPrefs();
                if (refs != null && refs != "") {

                    log.d("refs field: '%s'", refs);

                    synchronized (mEventLock) {
                        mEvent.remove(refs);
                        mEvent.put(refs, 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            synchronized (mEventLock) {
                // Upload event.
                upload(mEvent);
            }

        }
    }, INSTALL_DELAY);
}
```

Comment: It looks like in simplifying your code for posting, you made some mistakes. These mistakes make it too hard to guess what your actual code is doing.

Comment: What do you mean by "alien method upload does not *break the thread safety* of my object"? Are you worried about race conditions? Visibility issues?

Comment: Apologies have adjusted code. Am worried passing object of to an external function, delayFunction getting called again and changing the object if I don't lock upload(), but then it seems drastic to lock all of the upload() call and lock it up for all that time.

Comment: Is this the whole class or are there other methods / members? If there are, it would make sense to post the full code (unless it's really long and unrelated, but any use of mEvent would be related).

Comment: There are other methods, the upload method us public and can take objects from outside this class.

Comment: It is really long and unrelated unfortunately, that's why I edited, mEvent is only used in this function.

Comment: @slipp3ry In that case why don't you make it a local variable instead of a member and remove the synchronization (see my answer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve in your code:

- `delayFunction` starts by assigning `e` to `mEvent`
- then you modify mEvents
- then you upload mEvents

Why don't you simply make a local copy of `e` and work on that copy without synchronization?

Also, `mEvent` could be modified by another thread between `mEvent = e` and the runnable execution because you exit the synchronized block: your runnable would then be working on another `e` and you will have missed an upload.

But maybe that's on purpose.

Comment: I looked into copying but there is no standard copy for objects and mEvent does not implement copyable? It's OK if mEvent gets updated before the runnable execution happens but not if it happens between remove/update and upload. Should I put all of run in the block? That seems even more extreme.

Comment: Do you have a link to some javadoc for Values / ContentValues? Maybe a copy constructor?

Comment: Is it that ContentValues: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html

Comment: `ContentValues copy = new ContentValues(e);`